# Android maven missing artifact errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, etsy

I have been at this for a day and half and need help figuring out why I still get missing artifact errors.

Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental about the way maven works, but I assumed that you need to have the android deployer because the android jars are not on maven. The deployer moves those android dependencies to your local maven repo. I've followed the instructions from the readme on https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

So why can't it download Etsy's jar, and why is it complaining about the support jar when I've already included it from my local repository thanks to the android sdk deployer????

Run As -> Maven Clean -> Maven Install

```
[INFO] Building AklOutdoors 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] The POM for com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.0.+ is missing, 
no dependency information available
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Could not resolve dependencies 
for project 

The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.etsy.android.grid:library:jar:1.0.4, 
com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.0.+: Failure to find 
com.etsy.android.grid:library:jar:1.0.4 in 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
```

resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

1. Maven in installed.
2. Maven Android SDK Deployer is installed with no errors.
3. Everything from the SDK Manager is installed including the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository
4. Android for Maven Eclipse is installed and Maven Integration for Eclipse is installed.

Here is My pom.xml

```xml
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>AklOutdoors</groupId>
<artifactId>AklOutdoors</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v13</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.etsy.android.grid</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Help and an explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven refuse to download aar packaged dependency from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903371/maven-refuse-to-download-aar-packaged-dependency-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is rather old/late, but for anyone that has run into this issue and stumbles upon this (like me), I believe the solution here is that the etsy lib should be declared as `<type>aar</type>` in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.etsy.android.grid</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <type>aar</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```