# Maven can't find dependency

Tags: maven, androidx

Playing with maven by trying to add Androidx appcompact library dependency to my hello world java maven project. I have updated my projects pom.xml by dependency:

```
<dependencies>

...

<dependency>

<groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>

<artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>

<version>1.1.0</version>

<scope>runtime</scope>

</dependency>

...

</dependencies>
```

and repository:

```
<repositories>

<repository>

<id>google</id>

<url>https://maven.google.com/</url>

</repository>

</repositories>
```

I have executed `mvn package` command and got error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact androidx.appcompat:appcompat:jar:1.1.0 in google (https://maven.google.com/)
```

What I did wrong?

According to maven repository package should be there.

Whole POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>google</id>
           <url>https://maven.google.com/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This artifact us also on maven central, so basically you can remove the 'repository' section

Comment: If you are inside a company network, I guess you have a proxy/firewall issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [java - Maven refuse to download aar packaged dependency from remote repository - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903371/maven-refuse-to-download-aar-packaged-dependency-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mvn clean install -U
```

this will force update your dependencies, also check your mvn syntax in the pom file, share your complete pom file if it still doesn't work

Comment: `mvn clean install -U ` not helped. I have added pom.xml in question body